# Download pdf/audio/video from page, click next page and do same dynamically

Tags: pdf, download, imacros, m3u8

I hope I can find some help, is my first time with imacros (I know algorithms, but I've never used imacros).

I am a participant in a website with videos and study material in pdf, and I want to download them so I can watch and study offline.

So, I'm logged into the page, and I'm going to the course I want to download, link:
https://www.****.com/course/cod/sc%6CTU1EaL7Z%9W/v/OQlrb2uhlnS%9W/c/KvcHnMerTdz%9W

I tried, with Chrome Imacros recording function of imacros to save  each action and repeating it to do the operation in next pages, I'll attach the script so you understand.

In the page, I download the video, I use the Adobe HDS / HLS Video Saver addon (withou imacros i can download any m3u8 with this addon), the link to open the addon is:
chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html

Is possible record actions of a another addon? even if this addon is just a new tab with specifc functions?
In this link, the m3u8 file is brought by clicking on the link inside the addon, the addon joins the parts and the download of a unified file of the video.
Then I click clear and close the tab.

I go back to the first page, and I click to download the pdf booklet and then click to download the pdf slide and after downlaod the audiofile.

Then I click on the next page, where there same structure page with a new video and other materials and I have re-created the process on this new page.

However the script is static, I want to leave it dynamic, to go on going on each page by clicking the "next page" button and the materials being downloaded in each one.

Another detail, that in the static there are some problems, in this part:
GOTO URL = chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html

imacros adds  "http://" and ignores after the "extension" the ":" and try to open in the new tab like this, imacros try open this:
http://chrome-extension//pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html

1 - How do I open it in the new tab exactly: 
"
chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html
"
?

2 - inside this addon page which is a new tab, it seems that imacros did not save the command to click on the link, which makes the addon download the m3u8 and merge all the videos into a single file.
So in this way, as the addon is not opened as per the link above, I can not download the m3u8 video. Its possible use this addon with imacros? if not, any another suggestions to download m3u8 using imacros?

3 - When imacros downloads the contents of this first page, it goes to the next page according to the next page button, but it does not downloads the contents of the second page, but download the contents of the same first page again.
How to make it go to the next page as the button and download the contents of the next page and not the first?

That is, I want to make this dynamic, I did the procedure 3 times to be easy to understand the static imacro to try to make it dynamic.
So I want do a dynamic imacro that will always click "next page" automatically regardless of how many pages it is and download the contents of each one of them.

In short, for the time being this static script can download the pdfs and the audio normally, is only with the problem that I mentioned in not downloading the contents of the next page and too the problem of not being able to download the m3u8 video with imacros using the HLS addon.

Script:

```
VERSION BUILD=1001 RECORDER=CR
URL GOTO=https://www.****.com.br/course/cod/sc%6CTU1EaL7Z%9W/v/OQlrb2uhlnS%9W/c/KvcHnMerTdz%9W
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=chrome://newtab/
URL GOTO=chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>Booklet<SP>pdf
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>slide<SP>lesson
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>audiolesson
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>lesson<SP>audio
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Close
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>page<SP>lesson
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=chrome://newtab/
URL GOTO=chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>Booklet<SP>pdf
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>slide<SP>lesson
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>audiolesson
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>lesson<SP>audio
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Close
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Next<SP>page<SP>lesson
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
URL GOTO=chrome://newtab/
URL GOTO=chrome-extension://pibndofbpkoaipoidbkephfhhnapkccn/download.html
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=B ATTR=TXT:Booklet
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SMALL ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>slide<SP>lesson
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Audiolesson<SP>Download<SP>audiolesson
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Download<SP>lesson<SP>audio
TAB T=2
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Close
```

Comment: I don't see any reason for the batch-file tag in this post. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. thanks!